# Python Selenium element is not visible

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to click a bunch of "a" tags on a webpage. These elements appear on the page on load without any clicking, scrolling, etc. I can see the tags in the Chrome dev tools, but they are not in the page source of Selenium (so likely added via Javascript). My webdriver wait here throws a timeout exception. Why can't these elements be located?

```
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.message-block')))
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try using By.XPATH? `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'some-xpath'))`

Comment: Yes I did. Same result.

Comment: Are these links inside an `<iframe>`? If so you need to switch to the IFRAME and then find the links.

Comment: There are iframes on the page, but these links are not descendants of any iframe.

Comment: A timeout doesn't necessarily mean that the element can't be located, just that it doesn't become visible within 10s. It's possible that some of the elements are hidden on the page. Have you run the locator in the devtools of your browser and investigated them?

Comment: @EvanHessler can you give us the error message displayed?

Comment: Turns out I wasn't logged in when loading the page with Selenium. That fixed my issue.